# Wicket checkbox not updating

Tags: java, web-applications, model, wicket

I am trying to get a checkbox with wicket. The problem is that, the list of the choices appears now on the page, none is checked but when i want to check one of them, it gets checked and then directly UNCHECKED after I release the mouse button. I am pretty sure it has something to do with the wicket model, because i get no exception starting the server, loading the page etc..

what could be the reason for that?

```
public class PackageSummaryPanel extends Panel {

private static final List<String> COLLECTED_DATA_CHOICES = Arrays.asList("Shot Report",
        "Analysis Report", "Reliability Report", "Costs Estimation", "External Report");

public PackageSummaryPanel(String id, IModel<PackageSummary> model) {
    super(id, new CompoundPropertyModel<PackageSummary>(model));
}

private void addCollectedData() {
    add(new CheckboxField("collectedData", fieldLabel("collectedData"),
            new SplitterModel(new PropertyModel<String>(getDefaultModel(),
                    "collectedData")), COLLECTED_DATA_CHOICES).);

}
```

here is the bean:

```
 @Embeddable
 public class PackageSummary implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(name = DEVICE_PACKAGE_SUMMARY_COLLECTED_DATA)
private String collectedData;

public PackageSummary() {
    collectedData = "";
}

public String getCollectedData() {
    return collectedData;
}

public void setCollectedData(String collectedData) {
    this.collectedData = collectedData;
}


 }
```

Comment: What does CheckboxField look like?

Comment: CheckboxField, SplitterModel and fieldLabel() are not part of any Wicket code I know. Unless you can point at code for those things I can't help you.

Comment: Are you interested in taking this question forward ZeleB? In the comment from @MartijnDashorst above, it is clear that providing help on this question requires more information about `CheckboxField`, `SplitterModel`(infragistics?), and `.fieldLabel()`. If you have resolved this problem, you could add more detail to the question and provide your own answer. But if you are not going to provide additional information, the question is unanswerable as-is, and you should consider removing the question.